# How do i get a css page included in my header page on other php pages on my site?

Tags: php, css

I have a header page which contains the HTML head and links to my css page.

```
header.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ManageSchool</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="Assets//favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body class="<?php echo $class ?>"> 
        <header class="header">
            <img src="../Assets/Logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
        </header>
        <?php include "menu.php"; ?>
        <hr>
```

when i include this in my other page the css styles don't apply.

```
courses.php

<?php 
    session_start();
    $pageIdentifier = "courses"; 
    include "Inc/header.php"; 
    require "Config/db.php";
    echo "<p>Courses you're enrolled in.</p>";

    $course_query = "SELECT courses.code, courses.name, courses.description FROM studentscourses JOIN courses ON courses.id = course_id where student_id = {$_SESSION["student_id"]};";
    $course_result = mysqli_query($conn, $course_query);
    $course_posts = mysqli_fetch_all($course_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

    <?php foreach($course_posts as $c_post): ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Code</th>
                <th>Course Name</th> 
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $c_post["code"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c_post["name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c_post["description"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<?php
    endforeach;
    include "Inc/footer.php"; 
?>
```

How am i supposed to import my css styles to all php pages?

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your warning! I am just testing stuff, this is by no means a final program, but you're right, it's always good to get used to only use best practice!

Comment: Your welcome, but please note that comments that only say thank you are not necessary on Stack Overflow and will be shortly removed. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, and you don't need to reply to a comment, but if you do want to take an action, then it's best to fix the issues in the question that the comment pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML link is relative to the http path of the current page

so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

when accessed at:

https://YOURURL.com/Inc/header.php

Will look for the the css file in the directory WEB_ROOT/Inc/

However when you include that file in your courses.php the url being accessed is:

https://YOURURL.com/courses.php

So if will be looking for the css file in the directory WEB_ROOT/

I suggest you move your CSS files into its own directory on web root e.g WEB_ROOT/css

and then change your link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```